Python の2次元リスト同士で該当するものがあるか調べたい
AA, BB, CC というソフトがあり、それぞれ

AAは Ver 1.0, 1.1, 1.2
BBは Ver 1.0, 2.0, 3.1, 4.1  (Verの数は不定）

というようにソフトとソフトに該当するバージョンがあります
こちらを、別の二次元リスト

CC Ver 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
AA Ver 4.0, 3.0
BB Ver 2.0, 4.1

というようなリストと照らし合わせ、該当するソフトとバージョン（この場合 BB 2.0 が該当）を取得したいのですが、リストや辞書内包表記を使ってもどのように書けばよいのか見当がつきません。
こちらどのように書けばよいのか教えていただけないでしょうか？

バージョン番号のソートに packaging.version を利用していますので、事前に Packaging をインストールする必要があります。
from packaging.version import Version

# master data
software_versions_table = [
    ['CC', '1.0', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3'],
    ['AA', '4.0', '3.0'],
    ['BB', '2.0', '4.1'],
]

# query data
software_versions = [
    ['AA', '1.0', '1.1', '1.2'],
    ['BB', '1.0', '2.0', '3.1', '4.1'],
]

#
matched_versions = []
for name, *vers in software_versions:
    sv = [*filter(lambda x: x[0] == name, software_versions_table)]
    if not sv: continue
    m = list(set([*sv][0][1:]) & set(vers))
    if m: matched_versions.append([name, *sorted(m, key=Version)])

print(matched_versions)

# [['BB', '2.0', '4.1']]


まさにやりたかったことができました！ありがとうございます。
